# How do I set the browsing folder path to the most recently used directory upon starting the macro?

Tags: vba, directory, outlook

I'd like to have a way to retrieve the most recent directory for which I saved my email attachments to. I'm continually saving attachments and it's a pain to scroll through all my directories on the browse folder dialog and I'd like to just have it open to the most recent directory I saved to prior.

```
Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
Dim ShellApp As Object
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
                   BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
        Case Is = ":"
            If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Is = "\"
            If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Else
            GoTo Invalid
    End Select
    Exit Function

Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

I'd like to be able to click on the macro and have the browse dialog point to the most recent directory used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Shell.Explore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-explore) method to open a specified folder in a Windows Explorer window. The parameter can be a string that specifies the path of the folder or one of the `ShellSpecialFolderConstants` values.

```
  ShellApp.Explore(folder_path)
```